# How to define multiple packages as trusted package in yaml

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have a `Spring boot` application where I am consuming data from `Kafka topics`.
For the Objects which I consume, I need to provide their package names as trusted packages.

eg.

```
spring:
   kafka:
     consumer:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
        group-id: group_id
        auto-offset-reset: earliest
        key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        properties:
          spring:
            json:
              trusted:
                packages: com.sample.cassandra
```

Now I have multiple packages which I need to define as trusted package.

For example I have `com.sample.demo`, but when I try something like this:

```
spring:
                json:
                  trusted:
                    packages: com.sample.cassandra, com.sample.demo
```

It doesn't work.

What would be the correct syntax to define multiple packages in the `yaml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML syntax for sequences is

```
packages: [com.sample.cassandra, com.sample.demo]
```

You can alternatively use the block syntax:

```
packages:
  - com.sample.cassandra
  - com.sample.demo
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved the problem as below

```yaml
packages: "com.sample.cassandra, com.sample.demo"
```