# How to configure `spring.json.trusted.packages` for Kafka Streams + Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Does anyone know how to configure `spring.json.trusted.packages` for Kafka Streams? I'm using the following config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaStreamsConfig {

    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfig(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(Map.of(
                StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getStreams().getApplicationId(),
                StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getStreams().getBootstrapServers(),
                StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName(),
                StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName(),
                StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName()
        ));
    }
```

My application.yml is the following:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    streams:
      bootstrap-servers: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092
      application-id: spring-kafka-test
      properties:
        processing.guarantee: exactly_once
        spring.json.trusted.packages: com.mypackage.streams.entity.kafka.*
```

But when I change the package of the entity published into Kafka, I'm receiving the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.mypackage.streams.entity.kafka.raw.Entity' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.mypackage.streams.entity.kafka, com.mypackage.streams.entity.kafka.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:129)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:103)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:569)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
    ... 9 more
```

Looks like the property added to the appplication.yml does not work.

Comment: Dont know if its the problem, but can you maybe try to define multiple packages like this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61610007/15359624) and not like you did: `spring.json.trusted.packages: com.mypackage.streams.entity.kafka.*`? I can't test right now if your package-definition does work in my projects.

Comment: @MalteGronwald I've got the answer from one of the contributors for `spring-kafka`. Please take a look. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2193#discussioncomment-2452894

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment I found a workaround. It is a bit hacky, but I haven't found anything more elegant and at least it works now.

I've modified my `applicationi.yml` and added `consumer` and `producer` sections with the following configuration:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        spring.json.trusted.packages: com.mypackage.streams.entity.kafka.*
    producer:
      properties:
        spring.json.add.type.headers: false
    streams:
      bootstrap-servers: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092
      application-id: spring-kafka-test
      properties:
        processing.guarantee: exactly_once
```

Then I manually added configured properties to producer and consumer:

```
    @Bean
    public JsonSerde<Entity> entityJsonSerde(
            ObjectMapper objectMapper,
            KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

        JsonSerde<FlatTransaction> serde = new JsonSerde<>(Entity.class, objectMapper);
        serde.deserializer().configure(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(), false);
        serde.serializer().configure(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties(), false);
        return serde;
    }
```

Now all configurations from configured `producer` and `consumer` sections are applied to my serde object. The exception is gone and app works as expected.